# Data Quality on date field

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm having problems to deal with date fields on string format, so I'm trying to sanitize the base. The default format date string in my base is "%d/%m/%Y", but since this comes from a csv file, probably is there some undesirable strings. I'm getting errors when I try to parse with:

```
parse_date('%d/%m/%Y',trim(e.checkin))
```

Like this, but every time I run I get a new problematic char:

```
 Illegal non-space trailing data '�' in string "25/07/201€"
```

What is the best way to deal with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Core in addressing this issue is in identifying those rows with "broken" `checkin` field

Then, you can just skip processing them like below

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH e AS (
  SELECT '25/07/201€' AS checkin UNION ALL
  SELECT '25/07/2016'
)
SELECT 
  checkin AS checking_string, 
  PARSE_DATE('%d/%m/%Y',TRIM(e.checkin)) AS checking_date
FROM e
WHERE REGEXP_CONTAINS(e.checkin, r'^(\d){2}/(\d){2}/(\d){4}$')
```

or you can come with the logic of treating somehow specially those broken values

I any case, using `WHERE REGEXP_CONTAINS(e.checkin, r'^(\d){2}/(\d){2}/(\d){4}$')`  approach allows you to control situation

Hope this gives yo enough directions

Comment: Yea! I knew it will :o)  Thank you for confirming!